# What is the syntax for `EntityProperty` `"Date"` and `"DateRange"` Qualifiers?

Tags: date-and-time, entity

Does anyone know how to get `EntityProperty` `"Date"` and `"DateRange"` qualifiers to return data?

It seems reasonable that you should be able to use the `DateRange` function parameters on the `"DateRange"` qualifier. Sadly that does not seem to be the case.

```
CountryData["UnitedStates", 
  EntityProperty["Country", "InflationRate", 
   {"DateRange" -> {DateObject@{1980, 12, 31}, DateObject@{2017, 12, 31}, "Year"}, 
    "Frequency" -> "Annual"}]]
```

It also seems reasonable that you should be able to pass a list of `DateObjects` to a `"Date"` qualifier but sadly that too does not seem to be the case.

```
CountryData["UnitedStates", 
  EntityProperty["Country", "InflationRate", 
   {"Date" -> DateRange[DateObject@{1980, 12, 31}, DateObject@{2017, 12, 31}, "Year"], 
    "Frequency" -> "Annual"}]]
```

So how are these qualifiers specified. No hints are given in the `"QualifierValues"` entity property either.

---

I have since tried a few additional methods with no luck.

The very inefficient mapping over each date which produces multiple internet calls to WRI entity server.  This produces a large jumble of an error without an error message.

```
CountryData["UnitedStates",
   EntityProperty["Country", 
    "InflationRate", {"Date" -> #, "Frequency" -> "Annual"}]] & /@ 
 DateRange[DateObject@{1980, 12, 31}, DateObject@{2017, 12, 31}, "Year"]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Also tried using `Dated` to see if it would avoid this error. All calls fail with this method.

```
CountryData["UnitedStates",
   Dated[EntityProperty["Country", 
     "InflationRate", {"Frequency" -> "Annual"}], #]] & /@ 
 DateRange[DateObject@{1980, 12, 31}, DateObject@{2017, 12, 31}, "Year"]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

I think these two may be bugs.  Well, definitely the first one.  I might be using `Dated` wrong in the second but the syntax seems to conform.

Comment: Did you try Ctrl-= "US inflation rate from 1999 to 2010"?

Comment: That doesn't give a useful result for me.

Comment: @chuy - it doesn't return an `EntityValue` expression for you?

Comment: @JasonB. it does, but the result is a single number.  I strongly suspect Edmund is looking ti get back a time series or something like it.

Comment: @chuy Yes. I would like it to return the `TimeSeries` object with the rates at the end of each year.

Comment: @chuy - from that input it isn't entirely clear, a single number seems appropriate for "inflation from yearX to yearY".  But the returned input shows how to enter a date range for a "Country" entity value call.

Comment: @JasonB. If you provided it with a list of dates, which both methods above do, you would expect to get a list of values back.

Comment: @Edmund - For this particular property it isn't obvious that you should get a list back.  You aren't giving a list of properties, which should always return a list of values, but a single qualified property, so you should get a single value back.  Whether the single value is a time series or a single data point is less clear cut.

Comment: Ah its "Inflation" you want. `EntityProperty["Country", "Inflation", {"Date" -> 
   Interval[{DateObject[{1990}], DateObject[{2000}]}]}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Interval` seems to be the right way to specify a date range for an `EntityValue` call on a `"Country"` entity.  Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>=</kbd>"US inflation rate from 1999 to 2010" to query for the linguistics, gives a returned expression,

```
Entity["Country", "UnitedStates"][
 EntityProperty["Country", "Inflation", 
     {"Date" -> Interval[{DateObject[{1999}], DateObject[{2010}]}], 
       "Frequency" -> "Monthly", 
   "SeasonalAdjustment" -> "NotSeasonallyAdjusted"}]]
```

This shows the syntax for a date range for this property is `Interval[{__DateObject}]`

This is a good use case for `EntityInstance`,

```
entity = 
 EntityInstance[
  Entity["Country", 
   "UnitedStates"], {"Date" -> 
    Interval[{DateObject[{1978}], DateObject[{2010}]}]}]
```

Then query for properties,

```
entity["InflationRate"]
(* Quantity[250.686, "Percent"] *)

entity["Inflation"]
```

[image]

```
DateListPlot@%
```

[image]

Comment: What is very odd is that `CountryData["UnitedStates", 
 EntityProperty["Country", 
  "InflationRate", {"Date" -> All, "Frequency" -> "Annual"}]]` returns a `TimeSeries` object.  However there appears to be no method to specify a subset of this data with either the `"Date"` or the `"DateRange"` qualifier. Seems to be a broken framework.

Comment: For me Ctrl+= for "US inflation rate from 1999 to 2010" returns the `EntitiyProperty` `"InfationRate"` rather than `"Inflation"`.

Comment: Oh, yes. Interesting work around with `EntityInstance` (+1). I don't like that the property is not holding the date range and don't want to change all my code for it. Currently use a list of entities and can just use `EntityValue[list, property,"EntityAssociation"]` on this list to get the information needed.

Comment: @Edmund - it isn't necessary to put the modifiers on the entity, you can give them to the property.  [here] is a snippet doing that.

Comment: @JasonB. Missing your "here" link in your comment.

Comment: d'oh!  https://pastebin.com/raw/JGE2ScGc